# What is this for loop doing?

Tags: c++

What is the for loop doing? I just can't understand it.

```
list<pair<int, double> > nabors;
list<pair<int, double> >::iterator i;

for (i = nabors.begin(); i != nabors.end() && dist >= i->second; i++);
```

Comment: Which part of the loop is confusing you?

Comment: I posted this question on behalf of a friend, I'm not a C++ guy so I just copy/paste it here and I showed him the answer... He was impressed with the fast replies of stackoverflow

thanks guys

Comment: Nothing is more powerful or dangerous than a collective hive mind of bored nerds.

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's finding the first element in `nabors` that satisfies the condition

```
dist < i->second
```

If no element satisfies that condition, the iterator `i` points to `nabors.end()`.

Comment: @Dominic:  Thank you for the correction; I just thought of that, came back to fix it, and found it was already corrected.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the code is clearer with `std::find_if` and an explicit predicate?

```
class further_away_than
{
    double dist;
public:
    further_away_than(double dist) : dist(dist) {}

    bool operator()(const pair<int, double>& p)
    {
        return p.second > dist;
    }
};

#include <algorithm>

// ...

    i = find_if(nabors.begin(), nabors.end(), further_away_than(dist));
```

Dunno, I'm just an STL fanboy :)

Answer (score 2):

you may want to check some STL and iterators tutorials.

here is one
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html